# How to convert SQL query with group by, aggregates, and joins to Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

So, I have been attempting to convert the SQL query below to an Entity Framework query. I have been looking at other questions that use group by, but I cannot get mine to work when following the same syntax.Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT w.WorkstationID, WorkstationName, MinEmployeeCount, 
OptimalEmployeeCount, MAX(Quantity) AS NumOfEmployees
FROM Workstation AS w
JOIN WorkstationRecord AS r
ON w.WorkstationID = r.WorkstationID
GROUP BY w.WorkstationID, WorkstationName, MinEmployeeCount, 
OptimalEmployeeCount
```

Currently, I tried several different EF queries (in Query Syntax):

```
Workstations = (from sta in context.Workstations
                          join rec in context.WorkstationRecords on sta.WorkstationID equals rec.WorkstationID
                          group sta by sta.WorkstationID into sta
                          select new ClientWorkstation()
                          {
                              WorkstationID = sta.WorkstationID,
                              WorkstationName = sta.WorkstationName,
                              MinEmployeeCount = sta.MinEmployeeCount,
                              OptimalEmployeeCount = sta.OptimalEmployeeCount,
                              NumOfEmployees = rec.Quantity,
                          }).ToList();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
group sta by sta.WorkstationID into sta
```

to

```
group sta by new { sta.WorkstationID, sta.WorkstationName, sta.MinEmployeeCount, 
sta.OptimalEmployeeCount } into grp
select new ClientWorkstation
{
    // Are you sure you want Max and not Count?
    NumOfEmployees = grp.Max(t => t.Quantity), 
    // other members...
}
```